# Finite region enclosed by two curves when $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ contain variable a

Tags: calculus, integration, area

I need to find the area enclosed by the curves $f(x) = x^3 - ax$
and $g(x) = (a-1)x^2$. $a > 0 $

This I can do by subtracting the integral of the "lower function" from the integral of the "upper function".

By equating $f(x)$ to $g(x)$ I got the points of intersection which are $-1$, $0$, and $a$. Since they intersect three times it indicates that neither is necessarily consistently the "upper function". From substituting $x=-0.5$ into $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ it can be deduced that while on the left side of the $y$-axis, $f(x)$ is the "upper function" and while on the right side of the $y$-axis, the "upper function" is $g(x)$. So I can integrate in two parts and get the answer like that.

I am assuming this way of calculating the answer is fine but I am wondering if there is a better or more systematic way of doing it. I know a possibility is to combine the two functions into one function and integrate, but that's where I get confused. How do you know which one to subtract from the other, since neither is consistently the "upper function"? Or does it not matter which one you subtract? Will I get the same answer or the same answer but negative? Wouldn't getting a negative answer for area indicate I did something wrong?

Comment: If you are finding the area with respect to x, you subtract the _lower_ function **from** the _uppper_ function. If the functions switch from upper and lower, it is usually done by summing multiple integrals all of which are in the form $\mathrm{upper}-\mathrm{lower}$

Comment: Using two integrals, as you described, is the best way to find this area.

Comment: You don't have to worry about which is which, When you are calculating areas you are always integrating $|f(x)-g(x)|$